# Ubuntu 16.04.3 Flickering With Nouveau driver, bizarre "corrupted" screen and freezing using Proprietary drivers. Nvidia Geforce 8200M Compaq CQ60

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on an old HP Compaq CQ60 Laptop. The default driver (Nouveau) flickers when something changes on the screen such as mouse movement, opening Firefox, etc. I've tried proprietary drivers. When the proprietary drivers are in use, it will be stuck in a boot loop, it will be in a low resolution and then go right back to the login screen, or parts of the screen will flicker and move up and down. I got it to a point where it would work normally but then it would freeze when I would open chromium and firefox. Windows 7 works perfectly fine. I can access a TTY. The issue happened right after I installed it and I have had this issue before with earlier versions (14.04 and 15.10). I've reinstalled previously multiple times and nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more digging and found that all I had to do what install a legacy driver *insert face-palm here*. Anyways I typed

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings
```

Works normally. I still get the weird splash screen but at least it works.

Comment: Just plugged in my HDMI GTX970M today for experiment in fresh Ubuntu 16.04.5 install and noticed many of the same symptoms you had with nouveau driver. In Additional Software Ubuntu recommends Nvidia 384.130 driver though. Are you still using the same setup without problem or have you updated drivers?

Comment: The screen died and I didn't bother to fix it. When I was using it though, updating would freeze with weird artifacts. I tried on other distros like Arch and Fedora and it was still the same. I just stayed with the legacy driver.

Comment: My solution was to select proprietary nVidia 384.130 drivers in Ubuntu Software Additional Drivers section. Then to fix minor screen-tearing found here: ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374405. Then to fix no audio over HDMI on laptop GTX 970M solution found here: askubuntu.com/questions/1008599/…. Now last problem is system immediately wakes up from suspend but I can look at that tomorrow.